# Trouble installing rails (LoadError)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm trying to install rails and have done

```
gem install rails
```

Which returns:

```
Fetching: rails-4.0.0.gem (100%)
Successfully installed rails-4.0.0
Installing ri documentation for rails-4.0.0
1 gem installed
Successfully installed rails-4.0.0
```

I then type `rails -v`

And that returns

```
/usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p448/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in `require': cannot load such file -- /Users/ericfilkins/config/boot (LoadError)
from /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p448/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in `require'
from script/rails:5:in `<main>'
```

Can anyone guide me in the right direction?

Comment: Why are you using sudo?

Comment: Sorry, typo. Fixed in edit.